# how to mathematically represent a matrix of vectors?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, tensors, information-theory

My problem is the following:

I have a dataset in particular have $4$ dimensions, for didactic reasons I need to represent this dataset as a $m\times n$ matrix array such that the ($i$-th, $j$-th) cell containing a $4$-dimensional data. So far I have not found as repsentar this mathematically.

Comment: Are you familiar with quaternions?

Comment: There is no obstacle to define a $m\times n$ array of vectors. The question is: what operations do you want to do with this array?

Comment: I just reviewed your suggestion, but my problem is more focused on computer science, I have developed an algorithm split of nodes in a tree regression, and mentally understand the solution which I have given to the problem but when I explain this solution, i need of an arrangement like the one I described to make everything easier to explain and understandable, I had thought of a "a matrix sets" or a "matrix suceción" but not if it exists

Comment: What you say is true, there is no obstacle that in fact do not require any linear operation, now please tell me how can formally define an array properly in the case of my problem, I know how to program arrays in lenguages as c ++ but do not know how to express mathematically arrays. Creo que tu debes poder hablar español, si es así dímelo por favor, creo que podría describirte mi problema de una mejor manera, de antemano te agradezco por tus respuestas.

Comment: I think you need to give some more context. From what you've given so far it's no problem just stuffing them into a matrix.

Comment: You can perfectly define a "3D" matrix. Math software as Matlab let's you do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794191/create-a-3d-matrix  Of course, what it's not trivial is how to define some math operations (n particular, multiplication) on such matrices. But you have not given us enough context.